# Wordpress/Woocommerce single product page add to cart next to each other

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I'm working on a website for my company which provide a database of rental cars.
we use woocommerce, woocommerce bookings and elementor.
the problem I ran into is that instead of having the calendar and add to cart button below each other it sits next to each other which creates a very ugly look.
Below a screenshot of the right layout from our main website and a screenshot of our new website. I tried different themes but it seems that the theme is not the problem in this case because the error occurred in all themes I tried it out with.

Links to images:

[Wrong Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNciA.png)

[Correct layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0kUW.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Regards

Comment: Can't see the screenshot, make sure you added it. Thanks

Comment: I've added the images! sorry for the inconvenience